# Elements still have margin even though margin attribute is removed

Tags: css

I'm trying to use [`this pinterest-like grid library`](https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/). The most outside tag, `ul having the class of grid`, have some margin, so I removed the attribute `margin: 20px auto`, but the developer tool shows it still has orange area which is margin.

I need to remove the margin so that I can cover the whole width. Like you see the image below, the margin area doesn't go away even though I remove all margin attributes in the library. Can anyone know why is that? Is there any attribute generating the margin other than margin attribute?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul class="grid effect-1">
  <li>
    <img class="..." src="..." alt="product" >
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
  max-width: 69em;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 25%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.grid li.shown,
.no-js .grid li,
.no-cssanimations .grid li {
  opacity: 1;
}

.grid li a,
.grid li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Effect 1: opacity */
.grid.effect-1 li.animate {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.65s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeIn 0.65s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a full code snippet? Nobody can really help with this pic

Comment: @kawnah Updated the post!

Comment: OK...kill off the margin, and also the `max-width: 69em;` and set it to either 100% or remove entirely and let me know what happens

Comment: Amazing, setting `max-width: 100%` solved it as well as killing margin. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to kill off not only margin, but also max width.

Change it to this:

```
.grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: It is!, very light, so enjoyed using it :)